# Hive Query: Selecting column over a partition based on a median of a different column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I need help in modeling a query as I am unable to do it.

My data is:

```
id   name   school   height
1    A      S1       10
2    B      S1       12
3    C      S1       14
4    D      S2       15
5    E      S2       16
6    F      S2       17
```

I want to select the name and the name with median height per school.

Expected output:

```
id   name  school  myval
1    A    S1    B
2    B    S1    B
3    C    S1    B
4    D    S2    E
5    E    S2    E
6    F    S2    E
```

Here, person B has the median height in school S1 and E has in S2.

I know we can get median using percentile. But I am not able to figure out how to select the value per partition basis.

Comment: if you have even number of observations in a group, the median wouldn't equal a value corresponding to a school. what should you do in that case?

Comment: Yes, this is an edge case. :(
Actually in my use-case I am good with the middle value. For even elements the middle value can be N/2 or N/2 + 1. That will not make a difference. I guess i should use some operation on ROWNUM?

Answer (score 1):

## below query will work :-

```
select 
  temp1.id,
  temp1.name,
  temp1.school,
  temp2.name 
from 
  (select 
     id,
     name,
     school,
     height 
  from 
     TABLE_NAME
  ) temp1
  left Join        
   (select 
      school,
      name 
    from 
      (select 
        id,
        name,
        school,
        height,
        SUM(height) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY school)/COUNT(height) OVER 
               (PARTITION BY school) as avg 
      from 
        TABLE_NAME) AVERG 
   where height=avg ) temp2 on temp1.school=temp2.school ;
```

Comment: Confirmed this works. well done . i was struggling with this whole day.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the median column

```
select a.id,a.name,a.school,a.height, b.median from your_table a join (select school, CAST(percentile(CAST(height as BIGINT),0.5) as INT) as median from your_table group by school) b on a.school = b.school;
```

Comment: This will not give the correct answer. You are selecting the median of height. Instead, I want the name which has the median of height in the myval column.